# La funcion for me esta tomando solo la ultima fila de mi csv, que esta fallando?

Tags: python, web, bucle-for, whatsapp-web

Quiero enviar mensajes en whatsapp de forma masiva pero personalizada entonces hice el siguiente codigo:

`

```
import pyautogui as pg
import webbrowser as web
import time
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv (“datos.csv”)
data_dicta = data.to_dict(‘list’)
celulares = data_dicta[‘celular’]
mensajes = data_dicta[‘mensaje’]
combo = zip(celulares,mensajes)
first = True
for celular,mensaje in combo:
    time.sleep(8)
web.open(“https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=”+str(celular)+“&text=“+str(mensaje))
if first:
  time.sleep(8)
first=False
width,weight = pg.size()
pg.click(width/2,weight/2)
time.sleep(10)
pg.press(‘enter’)
time.sleep(6)
pg.hotkey(‘ctrl’,‘w’)`
```

Pero el problema es que solo lo ejecuta para la ultima fila del csv.
¿Que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Parece que `web.open()` fuera del `for`. Por tanto, solo ejecuta una vez, al terminar (excepto que este mal indentado). Solución: indentar la línea

Comment: Creo que deberías usar comillas simples (**'**) o dobles (**"**) sin formato. Por cierto, la identación es importante en Python. Si no copiaste el código correctamente no podremos reproducirlo.